# When I choose image from gallery, application is crashed - Android

Tags: android, image, memory, android-gallery

When I choose some images from gallery, application is crashed. I guess I loose activity. Because after choose image, line 77 :mSchoolNumber nullpointer exception is given in InitialiseFields() function. As I researhed, its problem is memory. But I cannot solve it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_edit_profile);
    initializeFields();
    initializeListeners();
}

public void initializeFields(){

    mSchoolNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSchoolNumber);
    mUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUserName);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    saveInfoButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveInfoButton);
    editProfileImageProgresBar = (DonutProgress)findViewById(R.id.editProfileImageProgresBar);
    editProfileImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.editProfileImageView);
    imageLoader = ConfigFile.getImageLoader(this);
    mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    mSchoolNumber.setText(UniPromClient.getSchoolNumber().toString());
    mUserName.setText(UniPromClient.getUserName().toString());
    mPassword.setText(UniPromClient.getPassword().toString());

    //showProfileImageOnServer();
}

class ImagePickListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);//ACTION_GET_CONTENT
            intent.setType("image/*");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            }
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Bir Fotoğraf Seçin"), IMAGE_PICK);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data && data.getData() != null) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case IMAGE_PICK:
                    this.imageFromGallery(resultCode, data);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void imageFromGallery(int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try{

        pd.show();
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        File file = new File(filePath);
        cursor.close();
        //sendProfileImage(file,filePath);//Bunu kaldırıp dene bir de    

    }catch(Exception e){

    }

}
```

-------------------- XML File-------------------

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.unipromapp.uniprom.unipromapp.LoginActivity"
android:background="@drawable/mainbackgorund">

<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_profile_layoutshape"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/editProfileImageView"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:src="@drawable/editprofile"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
                android:id="@+id/editProfileImageProgresBar"
                custom:donut_background_color="#DDFFFFFF"
                custom:donut_finished_stroke_width="4dp"
                custom:donut_progress="0"
                custom:donut_text_size="20dp"
                custom:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="4dp"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/editTextHint"
            android:theme="@style/MyTextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editSchoolNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:editable="false"
                android:hint="@string/userLoginName"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/editText" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/editTextHint"
            android:theme="@style/MyTextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/userName"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/editText" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/editTextHint"
            android:theme="@style/MyTextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/editText" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveInfoButton"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/editprofile_buttonshape"
            android:text="@string/saveInfo"
            android:textColor="#d1d5d0"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

----------------------------------Application gives this error--------------------

> 20 21:25:57.783 1627-1627/com.unipromapp.uniprom.unipromapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.unipromapp.uniprom.unipromapp, PID: 1627
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.unipromapp.uniprom.unipromapp/com.unipromapp.uniprom.unipromapp.UserEditProfileActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
>                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                        at
>   com.unipromapp.uniprom.unipromapp.UserEditProfileActivity.initializeFields(UserEditProfileActivity.java:77)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.unipromapp.uniprom.unipromapp.UserEditProfileActivity.onCreate(UserEditProfileActivity.java:62)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142) 
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606) 
>                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What is line 77 in the file?

Comment: Post your layout XML also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: line 77: mSchoolNumber

Comment: What is this line mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); in your initializeFields() doing ?

Comment: @fuat : remove the line mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); and then run the code.

Comment: @RakshitNawani I tried. It doesn't work. I is not important sense